Cant create a new entity in nestjs using typeorm - EntityMetadataNotFoundError
Hello i ve been having some problems with typeorm, i am trying to add a new entity to my current project, and i do the following :
i created a new entity
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, JoinColumn, OneToOne } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Requirement {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column()
    seats: number;

    @Column()
    points: number;
}

and added it to my module
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Requirement, ....)]

and the table gets correctly created in the database.
i have created a test function to call:
  async test(){
    const req = new Requirement();
    req.seats = 6; 
    req.points = 40;
    return this.requirementRepository.save(req);
  }

this is how i created the repository  :
    @InjectRepository(Requirement)
    private readonly requirementRepository: Repository<Requirement>,

i get this error
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Requirement" was found.
    at DataSource.getMetadata (/home/m/work/c/Website-Backend/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:427:30)
    at Repository.get metadata [as metadata] (/home/m/work/c/Website-Backend/src/repository/Repository.ts:52:40)
    at Repository.save (/home/m/work/c/Website-Backend/src/repository/Repository.ts:205:18)
    at ProgramsService.test (/home/m/work/c/Website-Backend/libs/programs/src/programs.service.ts:38:39)

eventho the table gets correctly created.
Just to clarify the new entity i created is in the same directory of some other entites i already have that correctly works, i ll share my typeormconf:
...
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      port: 5433,
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      logging: true,
    }),

I am stuck i ve tried every possible way but i cant get it to work, thank you in advance.
It should be all set up accordingly to the documentation, but still having problems.

I guess that's related to trying to use the repository in module other than the one where you import the typeorm.forFeature and declare the entity. I have created a small example with typeorm 0.3 and nestjs 10 if you are interested: https://github.com/lhousaine/nestjs-10_typeorm-03
